# Copying and Pasting a Range from a worksheet onto another

Tags: vba, excel

I have been looking at several related questions and cant seem to get a working solution for my workbook. I am trying to make a "add new section" Macro/Button that will copy a range of data and paste it to the last row of the active worksheet.

My current code is as follows:

```
Sub EnterClientSection()
'
' EnterClient Section Macro
'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim copySheet As Worksheet
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

Set copySheet = Worksheets("Zdata")
Set pasteSheet = ActiveSheet

copySheet.Range("A70:G81").Copy

pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

'

When I run the macro, it simply selects the last row on the current worksheet but doesnt seem to copy or paste anything.

"Zdata" is where the range of cells I would like to copy is stored.

Thank you for any with this :)

Comment: As a starter, try defining `pastesheet` by the actual sheet name.

Comment: Thank you, It didnt seem to change much. I changed it in pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1)... Was there anywhere else this change should be made.

Comment: What I meant was that in this line `Set pasteSheet = ...` you use a sheet name as you did in the line above, in case the active sheet is not what you think it is.

Comment: Gotcha! unfortunately its still doing the same thing.

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong. Have you stepped through the code line by line to see what's happening? You definitely have data in A70:G81?

Comment: Thank you for continuing to help.. The code actually gives me no errors- it just selects about 11 rows of Data on my active worksheet and that's all I believe. the debugger doesn't catch anything either

Comment: Is it going to a specific place on a different sheet? OR is it going to be filling in row by row ?

Comment: Hello, the Range would be pasted directly below the last row in the current worksheet.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that the last row is not where you think it is - have you checked it's not being pasted at row 10000 or something odd?

Comment: I checked and it still seems to be selecting the rows on the correct worksheet, but not pasting anything. I am sorry this is being such a pain.

Comment: In follow-up in worked! Thank you so much for the help SJR. I made a silly mistake and had ended up putting Pastevalues instead of pasteformat. It went over my head that there weren't actually values, just cell formatting that needed to be pasted. Thank you again!